# Global variables in library that linked by multiple entities of a single process

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I've got static library that supplies logger services, and it's linked to several sub-components in my C/C++ project.

I'd like to set the scope of global variables that defined in `logger` to all those entities that are link this library (for instance, `log_level`), and I wonder if change the library to dynamic would do the trick... would it ?

Comment: You appear to be using the word "scope" in a non-standard way, and certainly the notion of "setting the scope of global variables" makes no sense. The scope of a global variable is global, that's why it is a _global_ variable.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, you want to have different `log_level` values for specific libraries that share the singleton `logger` instance? A shared library won't change anything for that situation.

Comment: @MSalters, i guess you're right, but i wanted to emphasis that if i link static library to several components in my process, it will generate separate instance of this library per each such component, and not enable sharing the global variables.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, i actually want the same log level for all components in the process. that's why i want to share the log_level with all components that are linked with my logger library

Comment: @Zohar81: If it really was a global variable, that should be the case already. Which is why a good question has the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem. Can you construct a `libFoo` and `LibBar` such that each has its own `libLog::logLevel` ?

Comment: @Zohar81 Could you improve your question with some sample code please? Ideally a [MCVE].

Comment: @Zohar81 Also are your _sub-components_ shared libraries actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not make clear what you mean by "component" and "scope".

If I understand correctly, you have a single program (i.e. single executable, and single process at runtime) which includes several libraries (what you call "components") and [some of] these libraries are linked to a common `logger` library. You want all these libraries to be able to set a common variable `log_level` defined in the `logger` library. Is my understanding correct ?

If you define the `log_level` as a global variable in the source code of the `logger` library (i.e. defined once outside the scope of any function), you will have access to this global variable in any other component/library linked to your program by declaring it as `extern`.

> @MSalters, i guess you're right, but i wanted to emphasis that if i link static library to several components in my process, it will generate separate instance of this library per each such component, and not enable sharing the global variables. – Zohar81 yesterday

No, the final linking will remove any duplicate of the same library. You may link the `logger` library either only once to the program or several times to every components/libraries (that are finally linked together to the program), the same single variable `log_level` will be shared among everyone.

```
// logger.lib : logger.h
extern int log_level;
extern void log(const char* mesg);
```

```
// logger.lib : logger.c
int log_level;
void log(const char* mesg)    { /*...*/ }
```

```
// component1.lib : component1.c
#include "logger.h"  // declare log_level as extern
void component1()
{
    log_level = 1;   // modifies log_level defined in logger.c
    /* ... */
}
```

Another (and better) way to do quite the same thing is defining you log_level variable as static and provide some kind of accessor, such as:

```
// logger.lib : logger.h
extern void set_log_level(int log_level);
extern void log(const char* mesg);
```

```
// logger.lib : logger.c
static int s_log_level;  // only visible to logger.c
void set_log_level(int log_level) { s_log_level = log_level; }
void log(const char* mesg)        { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: thanks for you comprehensive answer. Just to make sure, what if I want the parameter 'log_level' to be unique per every component that load the 'logger' library ? How should I implement it in that case ? thanks again !

Comment: @Zohar81: by "component", do you mean "static library" and by "load", do you mean "statically linked" to the logger library ? if all these libraries are linked to a single executable, you don't need to care about multiply linking "logger", the log_level variable will be unique.